# sumif returns 0,though the cell may have value 2 or more than 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem in excel.my excel workbook has a sheet (1), which have number in j5. In k5 there long if formula , which calculate data from j5 , `=IF(J5<1,"0",IF(J5<11,"2",IF(J5<21,"4",IF(J5<31,"6",IF(J5<41,"8",IF(J5<51,"10",IF(J5<61,"12",IF(J5<71,"14",IF(J5<81,"16",IF(J5<91,"18",IF(J5<101,"20",IF(J5<111,"22",IF(J5<121,"24",IF(J5<131,"26",IF(J5<141,"28",IF(J5<151,"30",IF(J5<161,"32",IF(J5<171,"34",IF(J5<181,"36",IF(J5<191,"38",IF(J5<201,"40",IF(J5<211,"42",IF(J5<221,"44",IF(J5<231,"46",IF(J5<241,"48",IF(J5<251,"50",IF(J5<261,"52",IF(J5<271,"54",IF(J5<281,"56",IF(J5<291,"58",IF(J5<301,"60",IF(J5<311,"62",IF(J5<321,"64",IF(J5<331,"66",IF(J5<341,"68",IF(J5<351,"70",IF(J5<361,"72",IF(J5<371,"74",IF(J5<381,"76",IF(J5<391,"78",IF(J5<401,"80",IF(J5<411,"82",IF(J5<421,"84",IF(J5<431,"86",IF(J5<441,"88",IF(J5<451,"90",IF(J5<461,"92",IF(J5<471,"94",IF(J5<481,"96",IF(J5<491,"98",IF(J5<501,"100",IF(J5<511,"102",IF(J5<521,"104",IF(J5<531,"106",IF(J5<541,"108",IF(J5<551,"110",IF(J5<561,"112",IF(J5<571,"114",IF(J5<581,"116",IF(J5<591,"118",IF(J5<601,"120",IF(J5<611,"122",IF(J5<621,"124",IF(J5<631,"126",IF(J5<641,"128","T"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))).`

In another sheet named April in n5 cell i have `=IF('(1)'!$A$5:$A$20905=APRIL!$A5,(SUMIF('(1)'!$I$5:$I$20905,APRIL!$M$1,'(1)'!$K$5:$K$20905)),0)` formula. This always returns 0, whether k5 has anything. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF('(1)'!$A$5:$A$20905=APRIL!$A5,(SUMIF('(1)'!$I$5:$I$20905,APRIL!$M$1,'(1)'!$K$5:$K$20905)),0)
```

you have a problem in the logical test. You are not comparing a cell to a cell but a range to a cell. This below is what you are looking for I guess

```
=IF('(1)'!$A$5=APRIL!$A5,(SUMIF('(1)'!$I$5:$I$20905,APRIL!$M$1,'(1)'!$K$5:$K$20905)),0)
```

Regards,

Comment: No, i have to compare whole column and sum those cells match the criteria .  thanks for your reply

Comment: IF('(1)'!$A$5:$A$20905=APRIL!$A5 ... : you can compare a cell to a cell, you can compare a range to a range but you cannot compare a range to a cell like this. the both sides of = sign must be of the same type. This will always return false